# java.util.Date.parse() throws an exception when parsing Wed Apr 03 00:00:00 BST 2013

Tags: java

Why is it throwing an exception, That date is pretty straight forward isnt it?

```
long date  = Date.parse(request.getParameter("date")); //Wed Apr 03 00:00:00 BST 2013
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
reportParams.put("p_date", formattedDate);
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException     at
>   java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Date.parse()` to parse dates. As you can see in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), that method is deprecated, which means it is replaced by another method. The API documentation even mentions what you should use instead: `DateFormat.parse()`.

Create a `SimpleDateFormat` object with the format that matches your input string, and use that to parse it into a `Date` object.

```
String text = "Wed Apr 03 00:00:00 BST 2013";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = df.parse(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you have the date at the end of the string. It should come after the month, e.g:

> Wed, 03 Apr 2013 00:00:00 BST

Please [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) for a full description. Note also that `Date.parse` is deprecated in favour of `DateFormat.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Date.parse is deprecated

2) Date.parse API says *It accepts many syntaxes; in particular, it recognizes the IETF standard date syntax: "Sat, 12 Aug 1995 13:30:00 GMT". It also understands the continental U.S. time-zone abbreviations, but for general use, a time-zone offset should be used: "Sat, 12 Aug 1995 13:30:00 GMT+0430" (4 hours, 30 minutes west of the Greenwich meridian). If no time zone is specified, the local time zone is assumed. GMT and UTC are considered equivalent.* But your syntax is none of the described.

3) Use SimleDateFormat instead